# What are the advantages of using an spring cloud config server (externalised configurations)??

Tags: spring, microservices, spring-cloud-config

I have been reading about microservices and came across the spring cloud config server and externalised configurations.

From  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

> Spring Boot lets you externalize your configuration so that you can work with the same application code in different environments.

Can't this be achieved using spring profiles without using externalised configurations ?

Quoting from [https://dzone.com/articles/microservices-architectures-centralized-configurat#:~:text=Centralized%20Config%20Server%20to%20the%20Rescue&text=When%20a%20microservice%20needs%20its,the%20configuration%20to%20the%20microservice](https://dzone.com/articles/microservices-architectures-centralized-configurat#:%7E:text=Centralized%20Config%20Server%20to%20the%20Rescue&text=When%20a%20microservice%20needs%20its,the%20configuration%20to%20the%20microservice).

> If maintaining a single configuration for a large application is difficult, imagine maintaining configurations for hundreds of microservices in different environments.
> That's where a centralized configuration server steps in.

Even if all the configurations are stored at one place we still have to create and maintain different property files for each microservices and each of their profiles right ? So how exactly is centralized configuration simplifying the process of maintaining configurations for large number of microservices in different environments ?